# how to make difference between two datetime fields result in hours , odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

i want to do the difference b/w two datetime fields and the result is in hours. i am not getting any error but this is not working. can anyone please help with this.

```
@api.one
@api.onchange('end_production_date')
def onchange_production_dates(self):
    begin_production_date=self.begin_production_date
    end_production_date=self.end_production_date
    production_duration=self.production_duration

    value = {}
    if not begin_production_date:
        return value
    if not end_production_date and not production_duration:
        duration = 1.00
        value[production_duration] = duration

    start = datetime.strptime(begin_production_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    if end_production_date and not production_duration:
        end = datetime.strptime(end_production_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        diff = end - start
        duration = float(diff.days)* 24 + (float(diff.seconds) / 3600)
        value[production_duration] = round(duration, 2)
    elif not end_production_date:
        end = start + timedelta(hours=production_duration)
        value[end_production_date] = end.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    elif end_production_date and production_duration:
        end = datetime.strptime(end_production_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        diff = end - start
        duration = float(diff.days)* 24 + (float(diff.seconds) / 3600)
        value['production_duration'] = round(duration, 2)

    return {'value': value}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `total_seconds` method on the `timedelta` object:

```
total_hours = (end - start).total_seconds() / 3600
```

edit: with 60 you get minutes...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your problem lies in the lines

```
duration = float(diff.days)* 24 + (float(diff.seconds) / 3600)
```

That's not the way to compute a duration in a single unit. The only fields that gives a cumulated time is `total_seconds()`. So you should do:

```
duration = float(diff.total_seconds()) / 3600.
```